# How do I make a Mac Terminal pop-up/alert? Applescript?

Tags: macos, popup, terminal, applescript, alert

I want to be able to have my program display an alert, notice, whatever that displays my custom text. How is this done? Also, is it possible to make one with several buttons that sets a variable?

Similar to batch's:
`echo msgbox""<a.vbs&a.vbs`

Answer (score 241, accepted):

Use [`osascript`](https://web.archive.org/web/20141112143109/http://hintsforums.macworld.com/showthread.php?t=91912). For example:

```
osascript -e 'tell app "Finder" to display dialog "Hello World"'
```

Replacing “Finder” with whatever app you desire. Note if that app is backgrounded, the dialog will appear in the background too. To always show in the foreground, use “System Events” as the app:

```
osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to display dialog "Hello World"'
```

Read more on [Mac OS X Hints](https://web.archive.org/web/20141112143109/http://hintsforums.macworld.com/showthread.php?t=91912).

Comment: Wait, you can abbreviate application as app?

Comment: The AppleScript engine will automatically replace it. Simply paste the line between the quotes in AppleScript Editor, when you hit Run, it replaces app automatically with application before execution.

Comment: Another typing saver: you don't need "end if", "end repeat", etc., just "end" is fine and AppleScript will insert the second word.

Comment: If you don't want the "Cancel" button but just want an "OK" button replace {dialog} with {alert}.

Comment: Hi Anne, it is possible to open dialog or any other way to send message to other mac connected with LAN using terminal?

Comment: 13havik, well I know it's old topic, but yes, you can. :) However you need to be logged in. e.g by terminal ssh. and then invoke 

    osascript -e 'display dialog "Hello!"'

Comment: How can I display a dialogue or alert without the buttons? I want to flash a series of text messages and don't want any buttons present at all and would like to control how long the messages are displayed.

Answer (score 71):

Use this command to trigger the notification center notification from the terminal.

```
osascript -e 'display notification "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" with title "Title"'
```

Comment: If Focus is on, the notification won't be shown.

Answer (score 63):

If you're using any Mac OS X version which has Notification Center, you can use the [terminal-notifier](https://github.com/julienXX/terminal-notifier) gem. First install it (you may need `sudo`):

```
gem install terminal-notifier
```

and then simply:

```
terminal-notifier -message "Hello, this is my message" -title "Message Title"
```

See also [this OS X Daily post](http://osxdaily.com/2012/08/03/send-an-alert-to-notification-center-from-the-command-line-in-os-x/).

Comment: This is simply so much better than the old osascript stuff.

Comment: This appears to not work in 10.7.5 (Lion), apparently no Notification Center in it.

Comment: `brew install terminal-notifier` also works if you prefer to brew.

Comment: **PSA:** On Mavericks and later this isn't needed, just use osascript's [display notification](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57412/how-can-i-trigger-a-notification-center-notification-from-an-applescript-or-shel), which is mentioned below in Pradeep's answer.

Answer (score 14):

#### Adding **subtitle**, **title** and a **sound** to the notification:

With **AppleScript**:

```
display notification "Notification text" with title "Notification Title" subtitle "Notification sub-title" sound name "Submarine"
```

With **terminal/bash** and `osascript`:

```
osascript -e 'display notification "Notification text" with title "Notification Title" subtitle "Notification sub-title" sound name "Submarine"'
```

#### An *alert* can be displayed instead of a *notification*

Does not take the sub-heading nor the sound tough.

With **AppleScript**:

```
display alert "Alert title" message "Your message text line here."
```

With **terminal/bash** and `osascript`:

```
osascript -e 'display alert "Alert title" message "Your message text line here."'
```

Add a line in **bash** for **playing the sound** after the alert line:

```
afplay /System/Library/Sounds/Hero.aiff
```

Add same line in **AppleScript**, letting *shell script* do the work:

```
do shell script ("afplay /System/Library/Sounds/Hero.aiff")
```

List of macOS built in [sounds to choose from here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/367828/359545).

Paraphrased from a handy article on [terminal and applescript notifications](https://code-maven.com/display-notification-from-the-mac-command-line).

Answer (score 7):

This would restore focus to the previous application and exit the script if the answer was empty.

```
a=$(osascript -e 'try
tell app "SystemUIServer"
set answer to text returned of (display dialog "" default answer "")
end
end
activate app (path to frontmost application as text)
answer' | tr '\r' ' ')
[[ -z "$a" ]] && exit
```

If you told System Events to display the dialog, there would be a small delay if it wasn't running before.

For documentation about display dialog, open the dictionary of Standard Additions in AppleScript Editor or see the [AppleScript Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/applescript/conceptual/applescriptlangguide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW59).

Answer (score 6):

### Simple Notification

`osascript -e 'display notification "hello world!"'`

### Notification with title

`osascript -e 'display notification "hello world!" with title "This is the title"'`

### Notify and make sound

`osascript -e 'display notification "hello world!" with title "Greeting" sound name "Submarine"'`

### Notification with variables

`osascript -e 'display notification "'"$TR_TORRENT_NAME has finished downloading!"'" with title " ✔  Transmission-daemon"'`

credits: https://code-maven.com/display-notification-from-the-mac-command-line

Answer (score 5):

And my 15 cent. A one liner for the mac terminal etc just set the MIN= to whatever and a message

```
MIN=15 && for i in $(seq $(($MIN*60)) -1 1); do echo "$i, "; sleep 1; done; echo -e "\n\nMac Finder should show a popup" afplay /System/Library/Sounds/Funk.aiff; osascript -e 'tell app "Finder" to display dialog "Look away. Rest your eyes"'
```

A bonus example for inspiration to combine more commands; this will put a mac put to standby sleep upon the message too :) the sudo login is needed then, a multiplication as the 60*2 for two hours goes aswell

```
sudo su
clear; echo "\n\nPreparing for a sleep when timers done \n"; MIN=60*2 && for i in $(seq $(($MIN*60)) -1 1); do printf "\r%02d:%02d:%02d" $((i/3600)) $(( (i/60)%60)) $((i%60)); sleep 1; done; echo "\n\n Time to sleep  zzZZ";  afplay /System/Library/Sounds/Funk.aiff; osascript -e 'tell app "Finder" to display dialog "Time to sleep zzZZ"'; shutdown -h +1 -s
```

Answer (score -2):

I made a script to solve this which is [here](https://github.com/akashaggarwal7/tsay).
Installation:
`brew install akashaggarwal7/tools/tsay`
Usage:
`sleep 5; tsay`

Feel free to contribute!

Comment: "don't need any extra software... just install this" that's extra software.

Comment: @PRS its a script that runs commands available to the macOS already, not a software.

Comment: then why do I have to install brew and your script? see what I mean? ;)

Comment: however I'll give you credit for introducing me to the say command... I learned something new today! lol

Comment: @PRS Glad you came across say command, its quite useful. About your other comment I think if you're a developer brew is pretty common for you to use. And about installing the script, well feel free to open the source of the script and copy/paste it locally in a file and chmod +x it and run it ;)

Comment: he was just trying to have an easy way for others to run his simple script - not everyone on the internet is a programmer :D