# ios uialertview through mobile terminal command

Tags: ios, ssh, terminal, uialertview, sh

Is there a terminal utility for ios or a script that can be written so that with a command into mobile terminal or through ssh, a uialertview will pop up?

For example, into terminal, i type in  >alert [message] [title] [buttonmessage]
and an alert on the screen pops up with the specified parameters.

Comment: [click here][1] 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5588064/how-do-i-make-a-mac-terminal-pop-up-alert-applescript


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5588064/how-do-i-make-a-mac-terminal-pop-up-alert-applescript

Answer (score 0):

[image]Use osascript, for example:

```
osascript -e 'tell app "Finder" to display dialog "Hello World"' 
osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to display dialog "Hello World"'
```