# Show pop up message on MacOS

Tags: macos, macos-sierra

Is there any ready to use application to show pop-up message on MacOS?   For example, on Linux I can use "notify-send". Tried to search but couldn't get anything useful. Can any buddy lend a hand. Thanks a lot.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5588064/how-do-i-make-a-mac-terminal-pop-up-alert-applescript

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

`osascript -e 'display notification "Some translated test" with title "Quick translate"'`

and it was found in mentioned above topic